# Can replay transactions effect both chains? or just the minority hard fork chain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain-fork, replay-attack

Can a seg2x transaction be replayed on the main bitcoin CORE chain?

I was reading that only the minority hard fork would need replay protection and that coins on the main majority chain would be safe

Answer (score 1):

> Can a seg2x transaction be replayed on the main bitcoin CORE chain?

yes

> only the minority hard fork would need replay protection and that coins on the main majority chain would be safe

(a)this is wrong (b)nobody knows what chain will be major, what minor

Comment: What if the CORE chain does become the majority chain with significantly more mining support behind it... would having that majority hash power mitigate the issue at all? In other words are you saying both chains are at risk BECAUSE nobody knows what chain will be major, or that it doesn't matter which is major or minor, it has no effect on mitigating replays

Comment: A replay occurs when you intended a transaction to occur on one chain and it occurred on another chain instead of, or in addition to, the one you intended. The worst case scenario would be if you intended to send someone some low value tokens on the minority chain and that wound up executing on the chain with the higher value tokens.

Comment: So the higher value coins could become lost/missing in that scenario? Or the minority chain coins could become lost/missing? If I have coins on the majority chain and the minority chain, would selling my minority chain coins asap help protect me by keeping my value on the majority chain?  Or would neither be more safe than the other, both would be in jeopardy of lost/missing funds?

Comment: I think the majority/minority chain concept is misleading here. The problem is that a user intends to perform a transfer on one chain, and he creates a transaction for that chain. Due to lack of replay protection that transaction may also moves move the coins on the other chain (independently of which one is the majority or minority chain), which is not only unexpected for the user (he just wanted to move them on one chain, not both) and may lead to losses since the recipient of the transfer may not know how to handle the second chain, or won't help recover the funds for the sender.